# Javascript Know when object value is modified

Tags: javascript, proxy, datatrigger

For any variable or property thereof, is there a way to know when its value is set?

For example, say I have:

```
let x = { 'a': 1, 'b': 2 };
// x.a's set operation is linked to a method
x.a = 3; // the method is automatically called
```

Is there a way I can call a function when a's value is changed? Lots of code would be changing this value; I don't want to add the method call all over the place.

I'm aware of Proxies, but to use them seems to require a separate variable. Meaning, x can't be a proxy of itself.

Preferably this technique would work with primitive and non-primitives.

Comment: `Is there a way I can call a function when a's value is changed?` use setters and getters

Comment: Sure `x` can be a Proxy....  `x = new Proxy(x, handler)`

Comment: @charlietfl - Wouldn't that cause a loop? The handler would include a set method which would trigger itself.

Comment: the handler shouldn't use `x.` anything since setting a value will call `set: function(obj, prop, value) {` ... so `obj[prop] = value` won't *loop* :p but `x[prop] = value` would not be good

Comment: @Karric basic example works fine https://jsfiddle.net/3pfyxu9j/

Comment: @charlietfl - Thanks for the fiddle. Sounds like Proxy is the better way to go. If you post this as an answer, I'll upvote it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> x can't be a proxy of itself

Sure it can. You can change the variable to point to a Proxy by simply doing

```
x = new Proxy(x, handler)
```

---

Primitive example:

```js
const handler = {
  set: function(obj, prop, value) {
    console.log('setting prop: ', prop, ' to ', value)
    obj[prop] = value;
    return true;
  }
};

let x = { 'a': 1, 'b': 2 };

x = new Proxy(x, handler);

x.a = 3; // the method is automatically called
```

Comment: I've run into an issue. Given x = { 'a': [1] }, and I do x.a = [2], the set trap is not called. Why? Is there a trap for re-assignment?

Comment: Can't reproduce here https://jsfiddle.net/7uxjmszf/. Same demo as in comments above, I just changed to array values

Comment: Weird, your example works, I'll have to see how my code differs.

Answer (score 3):

> To be honest, use Proxy if you can

If you really can't use Proxy, you could achieve this using using setters and getters

Though it does mean re-declaring your original `x` object, I assume it's declared inline like the Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example in your question

```js
let x = {
  _a: 1,
  _b: 2,
  get a() {
    return this._a;
  },
  get b() {
    return this._b;
  },
  set a(value) {
    console.log(`changing a from ${this._a} to ${value}`);
    this._a = value;
  },
  set b(value) {
    console.log(`changing b from ${this._b} to ${value}`);
    this._b = value;
  }
};
x.a = 3;
```